# PHP MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, null

I very recently started learning php, and with the help of some examples I managed to make this code (mainly from W3Schools):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("Data Removed for Privacy");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql= "INSERT INTO EventRecord (PlayerName, EventType, Value, Time)
VALUES
('$_Get[PlayerName]', '$_Get[Event]' ,'$_Get[Value]' ,'$_Get[Time]')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

However, when doing something like

```
http://example.com/MyData.php?PlayerName=Test2&EventType=Test&Value=Test&Time=500
```

It comes up in my database as all of the values being null.

Additional information: The table has 5 columns, the four noted above and EventId (primary index, auto-incrementing). Sorry if this is a stupid question or I did anything wrong.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Your SQL code is very vulnerable towards SQL injection. Use prepared statements and bind variables or at *least* escape your variables.

Comment: It actually isn't, for the purposes that I'm using this for. Users can't submit their own data.

Comment: The only reason it isn't vulnerable is because you are using $_GET wrong. If you fix the problem that is giving you `null` for all your columns, then you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: If I'm the only one submitting data to the site, how am I vulnerable?

Comment: You can make typos. (Probably not one that will cause a security problem, but quite possibly one that will cause the query to abort).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`$_GET`** is a superglobal array , it should be in block letters and not like **`$_get`**

### Some disclaimers >>

- Never visit `www.w3schools.com` for browsing resources. You can find the reason [`here`](http://w3fools.com).
- Never pass foreign parameters like `$_GET, $_POST` directly into your query as it leads to SQL Injection. Switch to **`Prepared Statements`** such that escaping is automatically taken care of.

Comment: @Quentin, Thanks ! Deleted it.

Comment: I will certainly keep that in mind. I was only using W3Schools as it seemed like the best example for what I actually needed, though I'm learning the actual language at Codecademy, so I'll keep working on it.

Comment: Good and yes it's not your fault. Blame it on Google !

Comment: The downvotes am getting right now is probably from a trusted member of `w3schools.com` i guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

The expressions like `$_Get[PlayerName]` should be `$_GET['PlayerName']`. Here's why:

1. The variable you are trying to use is [the reserved variable `$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). But [variable names are case-sensitive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), which means that the variables `$_Get` and `$_GET` are not the same. So when you try to use `$_Get`, PHP complains about an "undefined variable".
2. `$_GET` is [an associative array, which maps integers or strings to values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). In your case, it maps the string `'PlayerName'` to a value, so you want to pass the string `'PlayerName'` to the array index operator. However, the unquoted string `PlayerName` is interpreted as a [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). This constant is undefined, so PHP complains about an "undefined constant".

Answer (score 0):

It's not

```
$_Get[PlayerName]
```

but

```
$_GET['PlayerName']
```

Otherwise you won't get the values.
Note both the UPPERCASE GET and the single quotes around the name!

Besides that, (Edit, not W3C, but:) W3Schools is NOT a good place to start learning, there are other and better resources available. You should NEVER use the $_GET or $_POST variables straight in your query!!!

Comment: Don't confuse the W3C (who produce web standards) with W3Schools (who write awful tutorials)

Comment: Very much true!!! Thanks for pointing out my mistake, changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: W3C is a wonderful place to learn - Seeing they produce the standards, as @Quentin mentioned.

Comment: @FrederikSpang It sure is, I mixed them both up, but corrected my answer! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$PlayerName=$_GET["PlayerName"];
$Event=$_GET["Event"];
$Value=$_GET["Value"];
$Time=$_GET["Time"];

$sql= "INSERT INTO EventRecord (PlayerName, EventType, Value, Time)
VALUES
('$PlayerName', '$Event' ,'$Value' ,'$Time')";
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer rather then just providing a wodge of code?